# Insect Infestation of Chinese Elm

Tags: identification, diagnosis, pest-control, pests

My Chinese elm suffers from an infestation that I am having a hard time diagnosing & treating. About a week ago, I noticed tiny, rod-shaped white spots, mostly on young leaves, which spread rapidly. Some close up images (complete set including videos [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rf3zf1676afyah0/AABF_QSfmo7USLW3eEeaheAsa?dl=0)):

[image: A relatively healthy leaf]

[image: Eggs]

Other possibly relevant information:

- Afflicted leaves suffer quite a bit, particularly the young ones.
- I've not noticed any other stadium of those insects, in particular no winged forms. That seems to exclude Whiteflies & Thrips. My googling skills have not turned up any other common pests that match those in appearance.
- I've submerged the tree in soap water for ≈ 30 minutes on two consecutive days: That seems to curb their population a bit, but it unfortunately quickly rebounds (within ≈12h).
- I am based in central Europe.

So, my question is: What could this be and how can I treat it?

Comment: Would you say fly's are pretty common around your house?

Comment: Not at all. The Bonsai sits on a windowsill facing a yard with a number of trees however, so it gets some limited exposure to what inhabits those.